# Can not link libmysqlclient.a?

Tags: mysql

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, and I installed `libmysqlclient-dev` package already. But I always get link error because `mysql_init` symbol missing.
My source code, Makefile, run-time result and symbol info are as follows:

```
igsrd@naivechou/~/project/m01/uuid_sign>cat main.cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "mysql/mysql.h"
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{   
    auto con = mysql_init(nullptr);
    //printf("mysql client version : %s\n",mysql_get_client_info());
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


igsrd@naivechou/~/project/m01/uuid_sign>LANG= && make -B
g++ -o main.o -c main.cpp -std=c++11 -ggdb
g++ -o uuid_sign -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -ldl main.o
main.o: In function `main':
/home/igsrd/project/m01/uuid_sign/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `mysql_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [uuid_sign] Error 1


igsrd@naivechou/~/project/m01/uuid_sign>nm -C /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a | grep mysql_init
0000000000002b10 T mysql_init
0000000000002d30 T mysql_init_character_set
                 U mysql_init_character_set
```

Source is very simple, just one line to call `mysql_init()`.
Making process shows every options for compiler and linker, I think there are no missing options.

Error message is `undefined reference` of linking error, so I dump `libmysqlclient.a` to grep the `mysql_init`, and it is not on undefined state.

Now I really have no idea. What's wrong with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your second command, try this (change the position of main.o):

```
    g++ -o uuid_sign main.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -ldl
```

Comment: I got it, I should link library first, then my object file, right?